How interpret contrary coefficient estimates in a logistic regression?
I need help to interpret a result output of a mediation analysis.
I have a predictor X that predicts three mediators variables M1, M2, M3 in a negative way. When X increases M1, M2, M3 decreases. M1, M2, M3 predicts a binary response outcome Y, but M1 and M3 in a positive way, while M3 in a negative way.
I am having some difficulty interpreting the result where the relationships between X and M are parallel, but the effects of M on Y are contrary across M variables. Could you help me?

I've found that it can be very hard to get an intuitive sense of what is going on in cases like this just from a table of parameter estimates, or a textual summary like what you provide.
What I like to do is make a table of predicted outcomes (here, probabilities) in different circumstances. If all your measures are continuous, you can look, for instance, at the results for the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd quartiles of each.
Trellis plots can also be useful.
